# Bounding rectangle on foreground objects for classification

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I have the the following program that draws bounding boxes on foreground objects.
This bounding boxes will aid in classification of objects by length, by measuring the length on one side of the rectangle.

Now, this only draws rectangle on only one object an instance, I would like to make it draw all of them simultaneously. But I'm stuck. Guidance or assistance needed. Please see images attached. [image: Foreground Mask![Original Image with Bounding Box drawn]

```
Rect boundingRect(InputArray contours);
    // Finds the contour with the largest area
    int area = 200;
    int idx = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<contours.size() ;i++) 
    {
        if(area < contours[i].size())
            idx = i; 
    }

    //cout<< contours.size();
    // Calculates the bounding rect of the largest area contour
    Rect rect = boundingRect(contours[idx]);
    Point pt1, pt2;
    pt1.x = rect.x;
    pt1.y = rect.y;
    pt2.x = rect.x + rect.width;
    pt2.y = rect.y + rect.height;
    cout<< idx<< "\t \t";
    // Draws the rect in the original image and show it
    rectangle(frame_Original, pt1, pt2, CV_RGB(0,0,255), 2);
    //cout << pt1; cout << pt2;
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to draw bounding boxes for all the cars in the image?

Comment: If you have all the blobs I think it will draw for all the blobs. Maybe you already rejected the others with conditions.

Comment: try this : http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html#bounding-rects-circles

Comment: Yes @code-gijoe. I want to do that. I'll try what the guys have suggested, then come back to update.

Comment: @MizukiKai NAhh, just very small contours that I have rejected.  On the video, it does show almost all, as the video plays. But keeps on jumping from one blob to another.

Comment: Thanks very much @AbidRahmanK... Article helped a lot. Works fine. Drew bounding rectangles for all objects at simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to draw all the rectangles in `countours` whose size are larger than `area`, you should save the index and then use a loop to draw all of them.

```
vector<int> idx;
for(int i=0; i < contours.size() ;i++)
{
    if(area < contours[i].size())
        idx.push_back(i);
}
for((int i=0; i < idx.size() ;i++)
    \\ Draw every contours[idx[i]]
```

Comment: I didn't know how to use the push_back method... Method explained above by @AbidRahmanK worked very well. The tutorial was easy to follow.

Comment: push_back just add an element at the end of the vector.